# Proof about sequences and $\epsilon-$ inequalities in a compact set $X$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, nonlinear-optimization

Could someone please explain why in the proof

1. $\Vert y-\overline x\Vert\ge\epsilon>0\ ?$

and

2. $f(x_k)+w_k^t\beta(x_k)\le f(\overline x)+w_k^t\beta(\overline x)\ ?$

In the **theorem,** $X(w)=\{y:y\ minimize \ f(x)+w^t\beta(x) \text{ over } x\in X\}$

**Theorem.**

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

1. As $x_k\to y$ and $\|x_k-\bar x\|\ge \epsilon$ for all $k$ (in $\mathscr K'$), we cannot have $\|y-\bar x\|<\epsilon$.
2. By assumption, $x_k\in X(w_k)$.

Comment: For 2. I know that $x_k\in X(w_k)$ so $x_k$ minimize $f(x)+w_k^t\beta(x)$. But why does the inequality holds? Why $'x_k\le \overline x'?$

Comment: For 1. Are the sequences $x_k$ the same? In the proof is a little bit confusing. I think it's clearer to denote the subsequence different $x_{k_n}$, so we would have $x_{k_n}\to y$ and $\|x_k-\bar x\|\ge \epsilon$